# Kubeflow, passing Python dataframe across components?

Tags: python, kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines, tfx, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I am writing a Kubeflow component which reads an input query and creates a `dataframe`, roughly as:

```
from kfp.v2.dsl import component 

@component(...)
def read_and_write():
    # read the input query 
    # transform to dataframe 
    sql.to_dataframe()
```

I was wondering how I can pass this dataframe to the next operation in my Kubeflow pipeline.
Is this possible? Or do I have to save the dataframe in a csv or other formats and then pass the output path of this?
Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the concept of the [Artifact](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/components/pipelines/sdk/v2/v2-compatibility/#building-pipelines-using-the-kubeflow-pipelines-sdk-v2). Quoting:

> Artifacts represent large or complex data structures like datasets or models, and are passed into components as a reference to a file path.

Comment: That's great 
How should I use it though? 
I think I have to pass to the input component `Output[Artifact]` where `Output` and `Artefact` are from `kfp.v2.dsl`. However, how to output this from the component?

Comment: There are many samples in the repo, here is one with the `Dataset` artifact: https://github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/blob/991473d3e42eb64a9ec5a7fc44a6733d1bd1db70/samples/v2/pipeline_with_importer.py#L47-L54

Comment: It is still not clear with example given in URL how to return dataframe from the component. Could you suggest some more resources please?

Comment: the link is broken (404)

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found:

- It's a good practice while using big set of data to transfert them from components to components through Artifact, which means share a commun file to read (Intput) and save (Output) data.

Here is one possible way to do it for Dataset, the component will load data from BigQuery and then save it to the output in order to use the df from the next component:

```py
@component(packages_to_install=["pandas","google-cloud-bigquery", "db-dtypes", "typing"])
def load_df_from_bq_to_csv(bq_source: str, DATASET_DISPLAY_NAME: str, location: str, PROJECT_ID: str, df_output: Output[Dataset]):
    from google.cloud import bigquery
    
    print("bq_source: ", bq_source)
    client = bigquery.Client(project=PROJECT_ID)
    QUERY = f"""SELECT * FROM `{bq_source}` LIMIT 1000"""
    df = client.query(QUERY).to_dataframe()
    print("Nbr of elements: ", df.shape[0])
    
    print("Writing df to df_ml_features file output")
    df.to_csv(df_output.path, header=True,  index=False)


@component(packages_to_install=["pandas", "db-dtypes", "typing"])
def print_df_nbr_rows_component(df_input: Input[Dataset]):
    import pandas as pd
    
    df = pd.read_csv(df_input.path, header=0)
    print("df nbr of elements: ", df.shape[0])


@kfp_pipeline(name=PIPELINE_NAME, pipeline_root=PIPELINE_ROOT)
def pipeline(
    bq_source: str,
    DATASET_DISPLAY_NAME: str,
    location: str = REGION,
    PROJECT_ID: str = PROJECT_ID,
):
    load_df_operation = load_df_from_bq_to_csv(bq_source=bq_source, DATASET_DISPLAY_NAME=DATASET_DISPLAY_NAME, location=location, PROJECT_ID=PROJECT_ID)
    print_df_nbr_rows_component(df_input=load_df_operation.outputs["df_output"])
```